# How to convolution integration(Duhamel Integration) by python?

Tags: python, response, sympy, convolution, symbolic-integration

Hi~ I'm studying about structural dynamics.
I want to make a code about Duhamel Integration which is kind of Convoution Integration.

If the initial conditions are y(0)=0 and y'(0)=0,
Duhamel Integration is like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsOb6.png)

**Using Ti Nspire**
I solved this problem with my Ti Npire softwere. The result is like that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4mUF.png)

Its response(y) of t=1 is -0.006238

**Using python(sympy)**
I tried to solve this problem using by Python(Jupyter Notebook).
But I couldn't solve the problem.

I wrote the code like this.

```
from sympy import *

t, tau=symbols('t, tau')

m=6938.78
k=379259
wn=sqrt(k/m)
wd=wn*sqrt(1-0.05**2)

eq1=(900*sin(5.3*tau))
eq2=exp(-0.05*wn*(t-tau))
eq3=sin(wd*(t-tau))

y0=1/(m*wd)*integrate(eq1*eq2*eq3,(tau,0,t))
y0
```

But I couldn't get the result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpRBp.png)

Is there other way to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPR2E.png)

Comment: The code as shown works fine for me and give `y` as a function of `t`. substituting `y.subs(t, 1.0)` gives `-0.00623772329557204` as expected so what do you mean by "I couldn't get the result"?

Comment: I chaged integrate into Intergral and could get the same result which I calculated using by Ti Nspire software!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unevaluated Integral and then substitute in a value for `t` and use the `doit` method:

```py
...
>>> y0=1/(m*wd)*Integral(eq1*eq2*eq3,(tau,0,t))
>>> y0.subs(t,1).doit()
-0.00623772329557205
```

To see the symbolic result before substituting `t=1` you need to help SymPy a little by expanding your integrand; I also evaluate floats to show only 3 digits from sake of simplicity:

```py
>>> integrate((eq1*eq2*eq3).expand(),(tau,0,t)).simplify().replace(
... lambda x:x.is_Float, lambda x: x.n(3))
245.0*sin(5.3*t) - 36.1*cos(5.3*t) - 174.0*exp(-0.37*t)*sin(7.38*t) + 36.1*exp(-0.37*t)*cos(7.38*t)
```

Comment: I could got the solution y(1)=-0.006237723 as your advisor. Additionally, how can I get the whole response like I got the solution using by Ti Nspire?   In my Jupyter notebook, when I use Intergral fuction, the result is not same as Ti Nspire's one. In which,  the integral sign is stiil remain.

Comment: I don't understand the output from Ti. The `y0` when using `Integral` has integral sign so I am not sure what you are seeking.

Comment: This is the output from the Ti. [Ti output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4mUF.png) You can see the result on the sencond line from the bottom.

Comment: But Sympy doesn't retuen the same result response like this  though when re result t=1 sec is same. [sympy rerult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPR2E.png)

Comment: SymPy needed a little help to do the symbolic integral. See updated answer.